# Can I limit write access of a program to a certain directory in osx? Also set maximum size of the directory and memory allocated

Tags: python, macos, memory, permissions

I am writing code with python that might run wild and do unexpected things. These might include trying to save very large arrays to disk and trying to allocate huge amounts of memory for arrays (more than is physically available on the system).

I want to run the code in a constrained environment in Mac OSX 10.7.5 with the following rules:

- The program can write files to one specific directory and no others (i.e. it cannot modify files outside this directory but it's ok to read files from outside)
- The directory has a maximum "capacity" so the program cannot save gigabytes worth of data
- Program can allocate only a finite amount of memory

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set up such a controlled environment?

Thanks.

Comment: For which python version?

Answer (score 0):

import os

stats = os.stat('possibly_big_file.txt')

if (stats.st_size > TOOBIG):
    print "Oh no....."

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'm afraid that by the time I call os.stat it will be too late: I want to prevent my program from trying to write a 10 gigabyte file to the disk in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and naive solution, that can be expanded to achieve what you want:

```
WRITABLE_DIRECTORY = '/full/path/to/writable/directory'


class MaxSizeFile(object):
    def __init__(self, fobj, max_bytes=float('+inf')):
        self._fobj = fobj
        self._max = max_bytes
        self._cur = 0
    def write(self, data):
        # should take into account file position...
        if self._cur + len(data) > self._max:
            raise IOError('The file is too big!')
        self._fobj.write(data)
        self._cur += len(data)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._fobj, attr)


def my_open(filename, mode='r', ..., max_size=float('+inf')):
    if '+' in mode or 'w' in mode:
        if os.path.dirname(filename) != WRITABLE_DIRECTORY:
            raise OSError('Cannot write outside the writable directory.')
    return MaxSizeFile(open(filename, mode, ...), max_size)
```

Then, instead using the built-in `open` you call `my_open`. The same can be done for the arrays. Instead of allocating the arrays directly you call a function that keeps track of how much memory has been allocated and eventually raises an exception.

Obviously this gives only really light constraints, but if the program wasn't written with the goal of causing problems it should be enough.